# Oracle sum query

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, sum

I have the following tables:

table entity with column entity_id, termination_date

```
    entity_id       termination_date
    401             1/20/21
    414             6/10/21
    402         
    403
```

table entity_detail with column entity_id, entity_detail_id, termination_date

```
entity_id   entity_detail_id    
425         401                 
425         414                 
425         402
425         403
```

table sleeve that has columns entity_id,period_end_date,one_month

```
entity_id   period_end_date   one_month
401         12/31/20              50
401         1/31/21               100
414         5/31/21               200
414         6/30/21               300

402         7/31/21               400
403         7/31/21               500
```

table agg that has columns entity_id,period_end_date,one_month

```
entity_id   period_end_date   one_month
425         7/31/21           I want this value = 400+500+100+300
```

entity_id 425 is the aggregate of entity 401,402,403,414.

entity_id 401 was terminated on 1/20/21. There is no data in table sleeve for this entity after 1/31/21.

entity_id 414 was terminated on 6/10/21. There is no data in table sleeve for this entity after 6/30/21.

For the agg table for entity 425 for 7/31/21, we want to add one_month for the following:

```
400 (from entity_id 402 - 7/31/21)
+500 (from entity_id 403 - 7/31/21)
+100 (from entity_id 401 - 1/31/21, the last month it exists, it's terminated on 1/20/21)
+300 (from entity_id 414 - 6/30/21, the last month it exists, it's terminated on 6/10/21)
```

How can we create a query that sums up one_month of the sleeves entity for 7/31/21, and also the terminated entities for the last month it exists (400+500+100+300 in the above data example) ?

We are doing this in a stored procedure, so it doesn't have to be in 1 query.

This edited query (based on the answer) will result in Total_One_Month = 1800 (instead of 900)

```
with entity as
(
select  425 as entity_id, null as termination_date from dual union 
all
select  402 as entity_id, null as termination_date from dual union 
all
select  403 as entity_id, null as termination_date from dual    
),
entity_detail as
(
select  425 as entity_id, 402 as entity_detail_id from dual union all
select  425 as entity_id, 403 as entity_detail_id from dual
),
sleeve as 
(
select  402 as sleeve_entity_id, to_date('7/31/2021','MM/DD/YYYY') as 
period_end_date, 400 as one_month from dual union all
select  403 as sleeve_entity_id, to_date('7/31/2021','MM/DD/YYYY') as 
period_end_date, 500 as one_month from dual
)
select r2.entity_id,max(r2.period_end_date), max(r2.sum_one_mth_ped1) 
max(r2.sum_one_mth_ped1)+sum(nvl(s2.one_month,0)) as total_one_month
from 
(
select r1.entity_id, max(r1.period_end_date) as period_end_date, 
max(r1.sum_one_mth_ped1) as sum_one_mth_ped1,
max(e.termination_date) as termination_date, 
ed.entity_detail_id
from 
(
select 
ed.entity_id, 
max(s.period_end_date) as period_end_date, 
sum(s.one_month) as sum_one_mth_ped1
from entity_detail ed 
join sleeve s on ed.entity_detail_id=s.sleeve_entity_id
where s.period_end_date = to_date('07/31/2021','MM/DD/YYYY')
group by ed.entity_id
) r1
left join entity e on trim(r1.entity_id) = trim(e.entity_id)
left join entity_detail ed on trim(e.entity_id) = trim(ed.entity_id) 
left join entity l5 on trim(ed.entity_detail_id) = trim(l5.entity_id) and l5.termination_date is not null
group by r1.entity_id, ed.entity_detail_id
) r2
 left join (
 select * from (
 select sleeve_entity_id, period_end_date, one_month, row_number() over (partition by sleeve_entity_id order by period_end_date desc) as latest_rec
 from sleeve) where latest_rec=1 ) s2
  on r2.entity_detail_id=s2.sleeve_entity_id
 group by  r2.entity_id;
```

Thank you.

Comment: Does the sleeve table have more than one row per entity_id? If so it might help for you to add multiple rows per entity_id for your example data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
with 
entity as
(
    select 401 as entity_id,   to_date('12/31/2020','MM/DD/YYYY') as termination_date from dual union all
    select 401 as entity_id,   to_date('01/31/2021','MM/DD/YYYY') as termination_date from dual union all
    select 414 as entity_id,   to_date('05/31/2021','MM/DD/YYYY') as termination_date from dual union all
    select 414 as entity_id,   to_date('06/10/2021','MM/DD/YYYY') as termination_date from dual union all
    select 402 as entity_id,  null as termination_date from dual union all
    select 403 as entity_id,  null as termination_date from dual
),
entity_detail as
    (
      select  425 as entity_id, 401 as entity_detail_id from dual union all
    select  425 as entity_id, 414 as entity_detail_id from dual union all
    select  425 as entity_id, 402 as entity_detail_id from dual union all
    select  425 as entity_id, 403 as entity_detail_id from dual
    ),
    sleeve as 
    (
    select  401 as sleeve_entity_id, to_date('12/31/2020','MM/DD/YYYY') as period_end_date, 50 as one_month from dual union all
    select  401 as sleeve_entity_id, to_date('1/31/2021','MM/DD/YYYY') as period_end_date, 100 as one_month from dual union all
    select  414 as sleeve_entity_id, to_date('5/31/2021','MM/DD/YYYY') as period_end_date, 200 as one_month from dual union all
    select  414 as sleeve_entity_id, to_date('6/30/2021','MM/DD/YYYY') as period_end_date, 300 as one_month from dual union all
    select  402 as sleeve_entity_id, to_date('7/31/2021','MM/DD/YYYY') as period_end_date, 400 as one_month from dual union all
    select  403 as sleeve_entity_id, to_date('7/31/2021','MM/DD/YYYY') as period_end_date, 500 as one_month from dual
    )
select r2.entity_id, max(r2.period_end_date), max(r2.sum_one_mth_ped1)+sum(nvl(s2.one_month,0)) as total_one_month
from 
(
    select r1.entity_id, max(r1.period_end_date) as period_end_date, max(r1.sum_one_mth_ped1) as sum_one_mth_ped1,
max(ed2.termination_date) as termination_date, ed2.entity_detail_id
    from
    (
    select 
    ed.entity_id, 
    max(s.period_end_date) as period_end_date, 
    sum(s.one_month) as sum_one_mth_ped1
    from entity_detail ed 
    join sleeve s on ed.entity_detail_id=s.sleeve_entity_id
    where s.period_end_date = to_date('07/31/2021','MM/DD/YYYY')
    group by ed.entity_id
    )r1
left join (select ed.entity_id,  e.entity_id as entity_detail_id, e.termination_date 
                from entity e inner join entity_detail ed on e.entity_id=ed.entity_detail_id 
                where e.termination_date is not null
                )ed2
on r1.entity_id=ed2.entity_id
group by r1.entity_id, ed2.entity_detail_id
) r2
     left join (
     select * from (
     select sleeve_entity_id, period_end_date, one_month, row_number() over(partition by sleeve_entity_id order by period_end_date desc) as latest_rec
from sleeve) where latest_rec=1 ) s2
      on r2.entity_detail_id=s2.sleeve_entity_id
group by  r2.entity_id;
```

Comment: Thank you Sunil. The query will return nothing when there is no entity that has been terminated. For example, aggregate entity 425 only has sleeve entities 402 and 403. How do we handle this in this case ? When I replace the 2nd and 3rd join with LEFT JOIN, it gives me the error "a column may not be outer-joined to a subquery"

Comment: Please check the modified query, left join is working for me.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. I am getting the error when I add "and s2.period_end_date = (select max(period_end_date) from sleeve s where s.sleeve_entity_id = s2.sleeve_entity_id )" to the 3rd join. I need to add this since I only want to get the terminated entity data from the last period_end_date. If I also have 414 for 5/31/21, without this statement, the query will add the 414 data from 5/31/21 and 6/30/21 (which I do not want)

Comment: Please check the updated query, if thats what you meant.

Comment: Thank you Sunil. In the original post, I modified your 2nd join (before r2) to include "entity" table (Please refer to entity and entity_detail tables in my original post). But, if there is no terminated entities (no entities 414 nor 401), the result is incorrect = 1800, it should be 900. When there are terminated entities, the result is incorrect also =  2100 instead of 1200. I must have done something wrong in the 2nd join (before r2)

Comment: Originally there were only 2 tables correct? Entity_detail and sleeve, how come we have 3 tables now? I changed the query again. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you so much Sunil ! That works ! Yes, in the beginning I thought I wanted to make it simple, so i didn't include the entity table. Thank you again !